# How to get dynamic result from Raw SQL Queries in Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to access some data through Entity Framework Core (v2.2.2) from a Sql Server DB, using a Raw SQL Query. My question is if it's possible to return a dynamic data result?

Taking the example bellow, we see that Blogs is an object that as been implemented and it can be mapped by a table on DB. Now i want that the result from the query could be anything, any columns size or type.

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
.FromSql("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs")
.ToList();
```

I have use this code example from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).

Comment: One answer: not. Use Dapper if you *really* want this (which I dare to doubt).

Comment: @GertArnold you read my mind! I have already a solution with Dapper that uses ExecuteReader, but this is in a standby mode until i find a solution with EF, if not i will use Dapper.

Comment: Yeah, it's uncanny... You can wait, but don't hold your breath. EF long ago stopped easy access to their Entity SQL API (shipped until EF6) that returns something like a DataRecord (if memory serves) which is a dynamic structure. And EF-core has nothing like it. It's not any ORM's core business, which is *statically* mapping relational tables to OO classes.